# Как узнать есть ли определённые права у пользователя?

Tags: mysql

Мучаюсь над проблемой получения информации о том есть ли права у пользователя на определённые команды к определённым таблицам. Например есть пользователь **user** и у него есть права на SELECT в таблице table1, а так же есть права на SELECT, DELETE в таблице table2. Как определить есть ли у пользователя права для удаления конкретно для таблицы table2?

Если использовать команду:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR user;
```

то выводятся все привилегии пользователя, что в свою очередь трудно автоматически обработать(точнее я не представляю как из меняющегося вывода выбрать DELETE который будет относиться именно к таблице table2 и не перепутать с другими таблицами.)

Если использовать команду:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.user_privileges;
```

то выводятся не все привилегии(в моём случае выводится только одна привилегия `USAGE`),

Если использовать команду

```
USE information_schema;
SELECT TABLE_NAME, PRIVILEGES FROM COLUMNS;
```

то привилегии выводятся только те, которые совпадают со списком "select, insert, update, references" т.е. в моём случае DELETE здесь нет.

Неужели никак нельзя узнать есть ли определённые права у пользователя?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, Вам нужно понимать, что в MySQL привилегии могут выдаваться на разные объекты

1. На весь сервер
2. На какие-то базы
3. На какие-то таблицы
4. На какие-то столбцы

Запрос

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR user;
```

Вам покажет **все** выданные привилегии для этого пользователя

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.user_privileges;
```

покажет привилегии, выданные на весь сервер

Что дает запрос

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, PRIVILEGES FROM information_schema.COLUMNS;
```

не знаю. Но привилегии пользователя по столбцам занесены в таблицу `column_privileges` (кстати, `DELETE` для столбца не может быть определено - нельзя удалить данные столбца)

А есть еще `table_privileges` - привилегии на таблицу и `schema_privileges` - привилегии на базу.

Я думаю, что Вашу привилегию нужно искать в `table_privileges`.

А вообще я бы посоветовал не заморачиваться этим вопросом. А просто пытаться делать определенное действие и проверять код ошибки

Проверить конкретно привилегию DELETE можно таким запросом

```
SELECT
  1
FROM
  user_privileges usr
WHERE
  usr.GRANTEE = :user AND
  usr.PRIVILEGE_TYPE = 'DELETE'
UNION
SELECT
  1
FROM
  schema_privileges sc
WHERE
  sc.GRANTEE = :user AND
  sc.PRIVILEGE_TYPE = 'DELETE'
  sc.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_db'
UNION
SELECT
  1
FROM
  table_privileges tb
WHERE
  tb.GRANTEE = :user AND
  tb.PRIVILEGE_TYPE = 'DELETE' AND
  tb.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_db' AND
  tb.TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'
```

Comment: Я прекрасно понимаю что привилегии могут выдаваться на разные объекты, отсюда и возник вопрос как узнать что на конкретную таблицу есть права на DELETE для определённого пользователя.

На счёт вашего примера

Comment: @ЧИМ Я привел запрос

Comment: Спасибо за наводку по "table_privileges" видимо там хранятся именно те значения которые мне нужны, вот только меня смутило что там не было прав root и другого пользователя с правами админа, но видимо они не помещаются в эту таблицу.
На счёт вашего примера, выдаёт ошибку на моменте "usr.GRANTEE = :user AND"

Comment: @ЧИМ так вместо `:user` нужно подставить имя своего пользователя

Comment: @ЧИМ т.к. привилегии рута будут распространяться на весь сервер, то ни будут лежать в `user_privileges`